# Need DateTimeFormatter for pattern 2011-05-08T07:33:00.000+05:30 in java

Tags: java, logic

what would be the DateTime formatter look for this DateTime format `2011-05-08T07:33:00.000+05:30` formatter in java?

want to build a datetime formatter for `2011-05-08T07:33:00.000+05:30` pattern

Thanks!

Comment: Done, just wanted a regex for the above pattern mentioned in new in the below code DateTimeFormatterBuilder(*******).appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.).toFormatter()

Comment: Proper grammar helps people reading your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need a custom `DateTimeFormatter` to parse 2011-05-08T07:33:00.000+05:30 as it is already in the default pattern used by `OffsetDateTime`. Note that the modern date-time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2011-05-08T07:33:00.000+05:30");
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
2011-05-08T07:33+05:30
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: I already have a prewritten code to support other formats ex. new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME)
            .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT)
            .toFormatter();   , need to addition for 2011-05-08T07:33:00.000+05:30 here

Comment: @VSJ - Your date-time string is of the format, `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`.